# How do I disable Civ 5's opening movie?

Tags: civilization-5

It seems like the opening movie always starts up and won't let me cancel it until it has played for about 10 seconds.  Is that because it takes the game that long to load regardless?  Is there a way to turn off the movie?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Since version 1.0.1.674:

- Go to the game options and check the `Skip Intro Video` option:

  [image: Picture of Skip Intro Video checkbox in Interface Options]

Earlier versions:

- Navigate to `My Documents/My Games/Sid Meier's Civilization V/` on a PC or `~/Documents/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5` on a Mac.
- Look for the file `Usersettings.ini` and open it in a text editor like Notepad
- Search for the variable `SkipIntroVideo = 0`
- Change the `0` to `1`

Enjoy your shiny, intro vid free Civ!

Comment: This works, although unfortunately it doesn't seem to have much impact on the loading time.  So I guess it really did just take that long to load, and the video is just there to help you pass the time.

Comment: Important note -- unlike some steam games, configuring the launch options for civ V with -nointro has no effect.

Comment: Interesting. It looks like there's an "Automated Workers leave improvements" option in that config file as well.

Comment: @bwarner in my opinion it does shorten the load time, and the user S3nd41 seems to agree as well.

Comment: Has a side benefit of my ATI card not forgetting it's 'overscan' setting and necessitating a visit to the control center.

Answer (score 27):

Unfortunately, the game takes that long to load regardless. You can turn off the display of the movie but there is no way to actually disable it so that your game loads faster.

Setting the SkipIntroVideo = 1 in usersettings.ini does not actually shorten the load time. Nor does removing the movie file from the root install directory.

You who answer to the contrary (@FallenAngelEyes & @Oak), I challenge you to actually get out a stopwatch and test it. Results below.

**Movie on:** 20.4 seconds

**SkipIntroVideo Set:** 19.95 seconds

**Movie File Deleted:** 20.4 seconds

**File deleted and SkipIntroVideo Set**: 20.1 seconds

Test procedure used:

1. Click the DirectX 10 & 11 launch option. *Start Time*
2. Click the mouse repeatedly
3. *Stop Time* when the ESRB Notice is seen.

p.s.
+1 to bwarner's original comment on the first answer about the load time not improving

p.s.s.
I realize now that because everyone has a different time before they can click to cancel the movie, it's probably just the game itself loading and not some bug where they force you to watch a certain amount of the movie. So it may not be fixable at all by Firaxis except by improving load times.

Comment: Very interesting, though honestly just the fact that it *feels* shorter is good enough for me :)

Comment: @Kaestur - good point, i've clarified the 1st paragraph.

Comment: I merely gave @bwarner the information he asked for regarding how to disable the movie; I never claimed it actually shortened the time. :)

Comment: The video is obnoxious after the third time. I'll settle for a long loading screen. :)

Answer (score 19):

Location of this file in the new Mac version:

```
/Users/username/Documents/Aspyr/Sid Meier's Civilization 5/UserSettings.ini
```

In Civ 5 Campaign Edition (purchased through the App Store) on Snow Leopard it is in the following location:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Civilization V Campaign Edition/UserSettings.ini
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case, on my Mountain Lion system. Neither `~/Documents/Aspyr` nor `App Support/Civilization V...` exists.

Comment: I don't have this installed on my Mac anymore but perhaps sometime in the next couple of weeks I can look back into it.  They must have changed something in the last rev or two of the OS.

Answer (score 8):

Disabling the loading movie also has the advantage, that you do not have to click the mouse to cut it short. You can open the game, and as soon as the game is ready the music starts.

Instead of having you wait for the old man to start talking and then clicking the mouse.

Comment: You can click/hit any key as soon as you see the 2K logo, which should appear nearly instantly.